# Amazon GameCircle Integration

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Amazon GameCircle and I have been able to successfully initialize GameCircle in my app, but the problem is when I click on the button that displays achievements, the GameCircle achievement list comes up but it says "You have unlocked 0 of 0 achievements". Same happens with leaderboards i.e there are no leaderboards for this app. I have created a Leaderboard and a few achievements on the online developer portal for Amazon but they don't show for some reason. Can someone help me with this. Any links/resources that help with integrating GameCircle will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help?  https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=92  See Amazon's reply with a list of things to try

Comment: Actually no, I have used the instructions in this link and the helped me in setting up Gamecircle but I still don't see the achievements I created. The link mentions a file "GameCircle-Developer-Guide.pdf" but I can't find it anywhere. I would really appreciate it if you could provide a link for the file or upload it or something (if you have it of course).

Comment: @amb
Also, if anyone has this file please share it with me. My email address is ibrahim@tintash.com. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  To solve it follow these steps:

1. Go to your Amazon Developer Portal (https://developer.amazon.com)
2. Go to "MyApps"
3. Hover your mouse over the settings icon on the right of the app in question and go to your GameCircle settings (also known as Game Services)
4. Click "Sandbox"
5. Enter the name of the Amazon GameCircle profile that you are using to test your application

That should be it!  It only takes a few moments to update so next time you open your app you should see both the leaderboards and the achievements.